# How to prove that all zeros of the complex polynomial $P(z)$ lie in $\Bbb{D}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, complex-geometry

I want to know how to prove that all zeros of the polynomial $P(z)$ lie in the closed unit disk $|z| \leqslant 1$. Where 
$$P(z)=z^{n+1}+\frac{2(n+1)\cos\alpha}{n+2}z^{n}+\frac{n}{n+2}z^{n-1}+\frac{2 e^{-i \theta}}{n+2}z +\frac{2e^{-i \theta}\cos\alpha}{ n+2}$$
$n\geqslant 1,\pi/2 \leqslant\alpha < \pi,\theta\in \mathbb{R}$.

We can write $P(z)$ as
$$\begin{split}
P(z)&=\left(z^{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+2}z^{n-1}+\frac{2 e^{-i \theta}}{n+2}z\right) +\left(\frac{2(n+1)\cos\alpha}{n+2}z^{n}+\frac{2e^{-i \theta}\cos\alpha}{ n+2}\right)\\
&=:\psi(z)+\phi(z)
\end{split}$$
where $\psi(z)=z^{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+2}z^{n-1}+\frac{2e^{-i\theta}}{n+2}z$ and $\phi(z)=\frac{2(n+1)\cos\alpha}{n+2}z^{n}+\frac{2e^{-i\theta}\cos\alpha}{n+2}$.
By **Cohn's Rule**, we can prove that all zeros of $\psi(z)$ are lie in  the closed unit disk $|z| \leqslant 1$. On the unit circle $|z|=1$, since $\frac{\pi}{2} \leqslant \alpha<\pi$, one can find that
\begin{split}
|\psi(z)|=\left|\frac{2(n+1+e^{-i\theta})}{n+2}\right|>\left|\frac{2(n+1+e^{-i\theta})\cos\alpha}{n+2}\right|=|\phi(z)|.
\end{split}
Then by **Rouche’s theorem**, we know that $\psi(z)$ and $P(z)=\psi(z)+\phi(z)$ have the same number of zeros inside the unit circle $|z|=1$.
Now my amazement is if some zeros of $\psi(z)$ lie on the unit cicle, can we show that some zeros of $P(z)$ lie on the unit cicle $|z|=1$, also? In other words, If all zeros of  $\psi(z)$ lie in the closed unit disk $|z|\leqslant 1$, can we prove that all zeros of $P(z)$ lie in the closed unit disk $|z|\leqslant 1$?

**For example:** If we take $n=10, \cos\alpha=-\frac{5}{6},e^{-i\theta}=i$, then $\psi(z)=z^{11}+\frac{5}{6}z^{9}+\frac{i}{6}z$ and $P(z)=z^{11} - \frac{55}{36} z^{10} + \frac{5}{6} z^9 + \frac{i}{6}z - \frac{5i}{36}$ , and all zeros distribution of  $\psi(z)$ and $P(z)$ are illustrated by the following images.

[image]  Zeros distribution of 
 $\psi(z)$ 
 [image] Zeros distribution of 
 $P(z)$

We can see that all zeros of $\psi(z)$ and $P(z)$ lie in the closed unit disk $|z|\leqslant 1$. But how to prove it? Ask for help!

Comment: Maybe the argument principle can be used.

Comment: One common approach to questions like "all zeros of $\psi(z)$ lie in the closed unit disk $|z|\le1$" is to establish "for all sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$, all zeros of $\psi(z)$ lie in the open disk $|z|<1+\varepsilon$". This, for example, can help Rouché's theorem work by moving the circular boundary away from potential zeros.

Comment: Your application of Rouche's theorem is incorrect, specifically your calculation of $|\psi(z)|$ and $|\phi(z)|$. You cannot simply substitute $z=1$ when $|z|=1$.

Comment: Prof. Jason.Yes, you are correct.I can not substitute $z=1$ as $|z|=1$. Thank you. But I want to know to prove all roots of  $P(z)$ lie in or on the unit disk.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $P(z) = \frac{1}{n+2} Q'(z)$, where $Q(z) = (z^n + e^{-i\theta})(z^2 + 2z\cos\alpha + 1)$. The roots of $(z^n + e^{-i\theta})$ then obviously lie on the unit circle, and the roots of $(z^2 + 2z\cos\alpha + 1)$ are given by $r = -\cos\alpha \pm i\sin\alpha$ via the quadratic formula. So, those roots lie on the unit circle as well. With this, the roots of $Q(z)$ are all on the unit circle, and by Gauss-Lucas the roots of $P(z)$ are all in the closed unit disc.

Finally, this also tells you where $P(z)$ has roots on the unit circle: it's precisely where $(z^n + e^{-i\theta})$ and $(z^2 + 2z\cos\alpha + 1)$ share a root.